# Call Main from another method

Tags: c#, function, methods

Is there a way to call `Main()` from another method "manually"? I have the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    # some code
    function();
}

static void function() {
    #some code
    Main(); # Start again
}
```

I have for example simple console calculator, when I calculate and print the result in `function()`, I want to start again with e.g. "Enter two numbers :" in `Main()` method.

Comment: of course, you can, but you haven't passed in any arguments. **BUT** you'll get a StackOverflow exception, reason being, you're invoking `code()` inside main then inside `code()` you're executing `Main`. **not** a good idea.

Comment: Please try to get a decent book or tutorial on basic programming first.

Comment: This is only example, my real code isn't too bad :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add the parameter as well. If you don't use the parameter in your main functin you have to possibilities:

1. Give `null` as parameter
2. Make the parameter optional

**null as parameter**

This would work like that:

```
static void code()
{
    Main(null);
}
```

**Optional property**

Then you'd have to modify the parameter like that:

```
static void Main (string[] args = null)
//...
```

---

You can't delete the parameter in the Main function because it is called by some other stuff, you don't want to modify.

If you do use the args parameter in the main function, null might not be a good idea, then you should replace it by something like `new string[0]`:

```
static void code()
{
    Main(new string[0]);
}
```

However, this isn't valid as optional parameter because optional parameters have to be *compile-time constant*.

If you use it with `null` you could get a *NullReference exception* if you use it without checking the value for `null` before. This can be done by two ways:

1. Using an if condition
2. Null propagation

An **if condition** would look like this:

```
static void Main (string[] args = null)
{
    Console.Write("Do something with the arguments. The first item is: ");
    if(args != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args.FirstOrDefault());
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("unknown");
    }

    code();
}
```

**Null propagation** like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args = null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do something with the arguments. The first item is: " + (args?.FirstOrDefault() ?? "unknown"));

    code();
}
```

By the way, you forgot a semicolon after your `Main()` call.

---

Maybe you should rethink your code design anyway, as you call the `code` method inside the `main` method and the main method inside the code method, which may result in an endless loop and therefore in a *StackOverflow exception*. You could consider to put the code you want to execute from the `code` method in another method which you'd then call inside the `main` method and inside the `code` method:

```
static void Initialize()
{
    //Do the stuff you want to have in both main and code
}

static void Main (string[] args)
{
    Initialize();
    code();
}

static void code()
{
    if (condition /*you said there'd be some if statement*/)
        Initialize();
}
```

---

[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_methods.htm) you can get more information about methods. But as this is a problem which normally occurrs at the beginning of learning how to code, you should probably go through a tutorial like [this](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/).

Comment: You write `static void Main (string[] args = new string[0])`, but that new-array expression is not a constant expression and cannot be used as a default argument for an optional parameter.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You're right - I'll update my answer.